# Spontaneous "NSCFString encodeBytes:length:forKey: unrecognized selector" exceptions

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, static-members

I'm using code that I've used in several other projects without incident. Suddenly, I'm getting random error messages when using the same code - but only in one particular project.

This code has run perfectly in several other projects:

```
@implementation MyClass

static NSMutableDictionary *elements;

+(void) initialize {
    if (!elements)
        elements = [NSMutableDictionary new];
}

+(void) MyFunction: (some parameters) {
    NSString *class_name = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    NSMutableArray *elementList = [elements valueForKey: class_name];
}
```

Something changed, and now the [elements valueForKey:] invocation produces the following error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: NSCFString encodeBytes:length:forKey: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

It actually gets weirder than that. If I step through +(void) initialize, I see that the elements is starting out as nil, and then getting set to an NSMutableDictionary, as expected. However, even immediately after that instance is created, any call to [elements valueForKey: [any NSString]] results in the same error about "NSCFString encodeBytes" not being a recognized selector.

(EDIT/SOLVED): The debugger wasn't actually complaining about the code at all - but rather the breakpoints: something about not being able to locate a breakpoint that had previously been placed there. Deleting Xcode's list of breakpoints for the project made it all better.

Comment: Can you think of anything other than your new code which has changed. Anything in your compile / build / link toolset? Can you still build your other working software that you made (using the same build options)?

Comment: David, if you fixed the issue you should submit it as an answer to your question in case others have the same problem :)

Comment: Thanks, Carl - I wasn't seeing the answer option last night, but that was probably from lack of sleep. :)

Answer (score 0):

The debugger wasn't actually complaining about the code at all - but rather the breakpoints: something about not being able to locate a breakpoint that had previously been placed there. Deleting Xcode's list of breakpoints for the project made it all better.